# Can I say ~~~必要となると思います?

Tags: usage

What I want to say is something like "if you choose A I think we will have to do B"

But of course in English (and in Japanese) there are many ways to say the same thing.

- If you choose A I think it will become important to do B
- If you choose A we'll need to do B
- If you choose A I think we'll need to do B
- ...

OR maybe even more of

- If you choose A I think you'll also need to choose B

But again so much nuance. In particular I'm asking someone what is their decision, A or X and I want to make it clear if if they choose A they'll probably also have to choose B.

For example: "If you choose to buy the car I think you'll also need to get a child seat.". In my exact case it's "If you choose the 3 monitor setup I think the game will probably have to be redesigned".

But there is subtlety in that there the "I think" part. In other word I'm not saying that how it is, I'm saying I think that's how it is.

So I was writing

「AにするとBにするのも必要となると思います」

but something just felt off. So I'm asking.

Comment: what should it be? "If we decide to buy the car then I think we will also have to rent a parking space". "if we go with 3 systems then I think the software will have to change". Stuff like that but I want to convey that if we *decide* on A then B will also have to happen. In other words, I'm talking to someone and trying to convey the implications of their decision.

Answer (score 3):

I think 「Aにすると(Aにするなら)、Bに(を)する必要があると思います。」is more natural.

For example, I translate "if you choose A I think we will have to do B" as もしあなたがAにするなら、私たちはBをしなければならない(する必要がある)と思います。"

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

I think it will become important to do B

- Bをすることが重要になると思います

we'll need to do B

- Bをする必要があります

I think we'll need to do B

- Bをする必要があると思います

"If you choose to buy the car I think you'll also need to get a child seat."

- 車を買うならば、チャイルドシートも必要となると思います。

btw, there is a slight difference between となる and になる

- 雨が雪になった // Rain became snow "naturally"
- 雨が雪となった // Rain became snow "unexpectedly"
- 彼に会った // I met him "accidentally"
- 彼と会った // I met him "as expected"

Are you confused? Don't worry, I'm also confused.

in this case, you should use 必要になると思います

Random Japanese passing thru.